# Xcode: Unable to add row to class with PFObject

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform

My app starts off by allowing a user to login with their facebook credentials, a user is this created in my Parse User class. This has successfully worked for multiple users who have tested my app.

One of the users is able to add items to a class called "Items" through PFObject, but the other users are unable to add any items. This is the code I am using to upload the object:

```
- (void)uploadItem {
NSString *title = self.itemTitle.text;
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber *price = [f numberFromString:self.itemPrice.text];
NSString *description = self.itemDescription.text;
NSString *category = self.category;
NSData *data;
NSNumber *mobileNo = [f numberFromString:self.mobileNo.text];
NSString *name;
NSString *userName = [[PFUser currentUser]username];

if ([FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc] initWithGraphPath:@"me" parameters:nil]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"fetched user:%@", result);

             _fullName = [result objectForKey:@"name"];
             _firstName = [result objectForKey:@"first_name"];
            _lastName = [result objectForKey:@"last_name"];
             _gender = [result objectForKey:@"gender"];
             _userID = [result objectForKey:@"id"];
             _locale = [result objectForKey:@"locale"];
             _email = [result objectForKey:@"email"];

         }
     }];
}

    UIImage *newImage = [self resizeImage:self.image toWidth:320.0f andHeight:480.0f];
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImage);
    name = @"image.png";


PFFile *file = [PFFile fileWithName:name data:data];
[file saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
    if (error) {
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!"
                                                            message:@"Please try sending your message again."
                                                           delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
        [alertView show];
    } else {
        PFObject *item = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Items"];
        [item setObject:file forKey:@"file"];
        [item setObject:title forKey:@"itemTitle"];
        [item setObject:mobileNo forKey:@"MobileNo"];
        [item setObject:price forKey:@"itemPrice"];
        [item setObject:description forKey:@"itemDescription"];
        [item setObject:category forKey:@"itemCategory"];
        [item setObject:[[PFUser currentUser] objectId] forKey:@"uploaderId"];
        [item setObject:userName forKey:@"uploaderIdFB"];
        [item setObject:_firstName forKey:@"FirstName"];
        [item setObject:_lastName forKey:@"LastName"];
        [item setObject:_fullName forKey:@"FullName"];
        [item setObject:_gender forKey:@"Gender"];
        [item setObject:_userID forKey:@"UserID"];
        [item setObject:_locale forKey:@"Locale"];
        [item setObject:_email forKey:@"Email"];

        [item saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {
            if (error) {
                UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"An error occurred!"
                                                                    message:@"Please try sending your message again."
                                                                   delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
                [alertView show];
            } else {
                // Success.
                self.image = nil;
                PFQuery *query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Categories"];
                [query whereKey:@"category" equalTo:category];
                [query getFirstObjectInBackgroundWithBlock:^(PFObject *object, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Error: %@ %@", error, [error userInfo]);
                    } else {
                        NSNumber *items = [object objectForKey:@"items"];
                        items = [NSNumber numberWithInt:([items intValue] + 1)];
                        [object setObject:items forKey:@"items"];
                        [object saveInBackground];
                    }
                }];
            }
        }];
    }
}];
}
```

Comment: This is not a question about Xcode.  Consider adding the [tag:ios] and [tag:objective-c] tags.

Answer (score 0):

One of the items you are saving must be null/nil. Break point each save and check the value of the object. If one of them is nill, it will mean the object wont save.